# Converting form number field value structure

Tags: javascript, html, forms

in a webpage, I asked users to input a field named "budget". I tried using the script below to create thousands separator for the entered number:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("project-budget").onblur = function() {
    this.value = parseFloat(this.value.replace(/,/g, ""))
      .toFixed(0)
      .toString()
      .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    document.getElementById("display").value = this.value.replace(/,/g, "")
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="project-budget" step="5" required type="text" pattern="[0-9]*" class="test input-item text-field is_number numberVal" name="et_budget" min="1">
```

it changes the value perfectly but the problem is that making the field value as text cause cms to not understand value in this field. so I need to change the value back to simple numbers in a hidden field and use that hidden field to insert value to database.
how can I change the value back?
for example user enters `1000000` and the script changes it to `1,000,000`. I want to print `1000000` in a hidden field.

Comment: Your script contains what you are asking for already … it already removes the `,` characters from the input so that it can parse the number as a float. So, copy & paste that part …

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help.

```js
function parseBudget(element) {
  const value = parseFloat(element.value.replace(/,/g, ''));
  console.log(value);
  element.value = value.toFixed(0)
    .toString()
    .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ',');
  document.querySelector("#forCms").value = value;
}
```

```html
<input id="project-budget" step="5" required type="text" pattern="[0-9]*" onblur="parseBudget(this)" class="test input-item text-field is_number numberVal" name="et_budget" min="1">
<input type="number" id="forCms">
```